# No rows are sent to destination flat file from xml source

Tags: xml, ssis

I am using a xml file to read which contaions multiple namespaces. And i have XSD file for that . which i am using. Now when i see Columns tab in XML Source Editor there are many output tables and columns. SO i settelled Some destinationa flat file for each table. But there is no output row from xml source to flat file destination. And package executes successfully.
While i cheked the xml file it contains values for each columns and its a huge file.

EDIT: One more thing is that i copied the data in xml file to another file and used that file then the error was realated to encoding "[XML Source [1]] Error: The component "XML Source" (1) was unable to read the XML data. Invalid character in the given encoding. Line 26003, position 81.
". So again confusing

I am using xml source first time to import the data from xml file to text file.
please help me out
Thanks!

Comment: And package executes succesfuly with no error.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved .
Actually my xsd files were 3 for this xml file. the 3rd file was importing other 2. 
Because the xml file have many namespaces. It was sily mistake but i think very important as well. As if you just use "generate xsd file" option in xml source editor then you can't generate it will give you an error that xml file contains multiple namespaces. So it's a nice idea to create xsd file which call other xsd files for respective namespaces.

Comment: I had the same issue after much frustration I noticed that a functioning XML document had an additional nesting level. So I added another dummy level in, generated the XSD and it worked. For example I had `<root><tag1/><tag2/><tag3/></root>` and this returned no rows. I changed it to `<root><anotherlevel><tag1/><tag2/><tag3/></anotherlevel></root>` and it worked. FRUSTRATING